# Addressfield entries not showing up when entityform sends an email

Tags: emails, entities

I have an [Entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) that uses the [Address Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield) module. Viewing a submission in the interface is fine. However, when the admin email goes out, only labels are shown; the address fields are empty. Has anyone had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This was addressed in an [issue on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2158723). Which version of Entity2Text are you using? The fix was added to 7.x-1.0-alpha2.

Comment: I had alpha2 and just up'd to alpha3, and it's working now, all addressfield fields with data are in the email.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with files attached via the entityform. The email contains the "Files:" label but no data follows. It would be nice to see the filename and/or Description for each file. I don't know that it's an E2T issue but thought I'd mention it. BTW, I forgot to say THANKS!